# Html Css Text wont stay under image in og-grid

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hey Guys so I have this html and css grid that I have constructed on a page. I am having trouble with the text on a mobile platform and when the web page is made smaller. This is what it looks like on a regular page:
[image]

This is what it looks like when the page is made smaller and the images shift vertically.
[image]
[image]

I the pictures and the text over lap each other and its very frustrating. I am posting the html and css below if anyone could help or give any pointers it would be appreciated.

```css
.og-grid {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 20px 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.og-grid li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px 5px 0 5px;
    vertical-align: top;
    height: 250px;
}

.og-grid li > a,
.og-grid li > a img {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

.og-grid li.og-expanded > a::after {
    top: auto;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    border-bottom-color: #ddd;
    border-width: 15px;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -20px 0 0 -15px;
}

.og-expander {
    position: absolute;
    background: #ddd;
    top: auto;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.og-expander-inner {
    padding: 50px 30px;
    height: 100%;
}

.og-close {
    position: absolute;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    top: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.og-close::before,
.og-close::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    height: 1px;
    background: #888;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.og-close::after {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.og-close:hover::before,
.og-close:hover::after {
    background: #333;
}

.og-fullimg,
.og-details {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.og-details {
    padding: 0 40px 0 20px;
}

.og-fullimg {
    text-align: center;
}

.og-fullimg img {
    display: inline-block;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.og-details h3 {
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 38px; /*THIS CONTROLS THE TEXT OF THE TITLE*/
    padding: 40px 0 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px; /*THIS CONTROLS THE SPACE BETWEEN THE TITLE AND THE DESCRIPTION*/
}

.og-details p {
    font-weight: 400; /*THIS CONTROLS THE WEIGHT OF THE DESCRIPTION TEXT*/
    font-size: 16px; /*THIS CONTROLS THE SIZE OF THE DESCRIPTION TEXT*/
    line-height: 22px;
    color: #999;
}

.og-details a {
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 16px; /*THIS CONTROLS THE SIZE OF THE LINK DESCRIPTION*/
    color: #333;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border: 3px solid #333;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 30px 0 0;
    outline: none;
}

.og-details a::before {
    content: '\2192';
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.og-details a:hover {
    border-color: #999;
    color: #999;
}

.og-loading {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #ddd;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px #ccc, 15px 30px 1px #ccc, -15px 30px 1px #ccc;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -25px 0 0 -25px;
    -webkit-animation: loader 0.5s infinite ease-in-out both;
    -moz-animation: loader 0.5s infinite ease-in-out both;
    animation: loader 0.5s infinite ease-in-out both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes loader {
    0% { background: #ddd; }
    33% { background: #ccc; box-shadow: 0 0 1px #ccc, 15px 30px 1px #ccc, -15px 30px 1px #ddd; }
    66% { background: #ccc; box-shadow: 0 0 1px #ccc, 15px 30px 1px #ddd, -15px 30px 1px #ccc; }
}

@-moz-keyframes loader {
    0% { background: #ddd; }
    33% { background: #ccc; box-shadow: 0 0 1px #ccc, 15px 30px 1px #ccc, -15px 30px 1px #ddd; }
    66% { background: #ccc; box-shadow: 0 0 1px #ccc, 15px 30px 1px #ddd, -15px 30px 1px #ccc; }
}

@keyframes loader {
    0% { background: #ddd; }
    33% { background: #ccc; box-shadow: 0 0 1px #ccc, 15px 30px 1px #ccc, -15px 30px 1px #ddd; }
    66% { background: #ccc; box-shadow: 0 0 1px #ccc, 15px 30px 1px #ddd, -15px 30px 1px #ccc; }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 830px) {

    .og-expander h3 { font-size: 32px; }
    .og-expander p { font-size: 13px; }
    .og-expander a { font-size: 12px; }

}

@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {

    .og-fullimg { display: none; }
    .og-details { float: none; width: 100%; }
    
}
```

```html
        <div class="container"> 
            <div class="main">
                <ul id="og-grid" class="og-grid">
                    <li>
                        <a href="" data-largesrc="images/HomePage/PII.png" data-title="INVENTORY TOOL" 
                        data-description="The Data Privacy Inventory Tool (DPIT) simplifies the compilation of a districtâ€™s software inventory as required by Education Law 2-d Part 121 Regulations. The DPIT provides a means for sharing a District's Parents' Bill of Rights, Supplemental Iinformation and compliance with components of the NIST Cybersecurity Framework - Identify Function.">
                            <img src="images/HomePage/thumbs/PIIthumb.png" alt="PII"/>
                        </a>
                    <h4>Image one</h4>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="" data-largesrc="images/HomePage/PBOR.png" data-title="PROFESSIONAL DEVELOPMENT" data-description="Web-based security awareness training that follows a structured outline, including a formal assessment and proof of completion.  The Professional Development modules were developed to align with Ed Law 2-d requirements for annual employee training on Federal/State Laws and Cybersecurity Awareness. <br/><br/>
Additional materials for instructor-led professional development are also available.">
                            <img src="images/HomePage/thumbs/PBORthumb.png" alt="PBOR"/>
                        </a>
                    <h4>Image 2</h4>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="" data-largesrc="images/HomePage/DSPolicy.png" data-title="DIGITAL DIGESTS, DEBRIEFS, AND BLASTS" 
                        data-description="Participation in the DPSS provides district administrators with just in time information on cyberthreats, phishing schemes and other privacy and security issues in the form of Digital Blasts.  Each quarter, a Digital Digest is published that provides in depth information, links and resources on a specific topic such as - Protecting Data in a Remote Learning Environment.  Industry experts are also interviewed as part of the Digital Debrief program providing information on these timely topics.">
                            <img src="images/HomePage/thumbs/DSPolicythumb.png" alt="Policy"/>
                        </a>
                    <h4>Image 3</h4>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="" data-largesrc="images/HomePage/NIST.png" data-title="NIST CYBERSECURITY FRAMEWORK RESOURCES" data-description="NYSED adopted the NIST Cybersecurity Framework (NIST CSF) as the standard for data security and privacy for educational agencies. The RIC One DPSS consists of many tools and reference materials to assist educational agencies with the implementation of the NIST CSF to comply with Education Law 2-d.  <br/><br/><b>Regulation 121.5</b>">
                            <img src="images/HomePage/thumbs/NISTthumb.png" alt="NIST"/>
                        </a>
                    <h4>Image 4</h4>
                    </li>
                </ul>

            </div>
        </div><!-- /container -->
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your elements to be vertical ,first add a class to all images (here I added img)then in media query of max-width 830px add

```
.img{
    width: 75%
}

.og-grid{
    display: flex;
    flex: 0 50%;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
}
```

Or if you want your images to be horizontal add

```
.img{
    width: 75%
}

.og-grid{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.og-grid>li{
    flex: 1 1 160px;
}
```

to your css

I hope you can understand :)

Comment: Hi they are only vertical when the screen is made smaller or on mobile. But the problem is if they are vertical the images go over the text. That is what I need help with.

Comment: Then try adding the above code for placing them vertical :-)

Answer (score 0):

You gave `.og-grid li` a height of 250px which wraps the image and text. You would have to give the `a` tag (that contains the image) to take a certain % of the total height so the text will fill the rest.

See code sample below

```
.og-grid li > a { height:80% }
img { width:100%, height:100% }
```

Comment: That still does not work... Am I doing it correct?

Comment: .og-grid li > a { height:80% }
.og-grid li > a img {
 border: none;
 outline: none;
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 width:100%, 
 height:100% 
}

Comment: could it be because you have a comma after width:100% instead of a semi colon?